# Spritebuilder Android UIFont and NSString Errors?

Tags: android, objective-c, xcode, spritebuilder

I can't compile an app I created with Spritebuilder - everything else in the app seems to work fine, but in a section I created to measure the size of a string (using the depreciated sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize:), I am getting compile errors about the UIFont.

I tried it with the new rectangle block (er... I forgot what it was, will edit later), but that is creating errors about NSString specific attributes that do not exist or something.

I'll update later with the actual error as I'm about to run off to work, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Or at least an explanation as to why this is happening. Does Spritebuilder not cover UIFont?

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [_testArray[index] length]; i++){
                if([[_testArray[index] substringToIndex:i]sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13.5f] constrainedToSize:size].height > 500) {
NSLog(@"This is working!");
}
```

The error in question is:

```
Semantic issue: Use of Undeclared Identifier 'UIFont'
```

Comment: What was the point of posting the question without the code and the error?

Comment: Do you really mean Android and not iOS?

Comment: Yes, I really mean Android and not iOS.